# How do I run the symfony framework project to server ubuntu?

Tags: symfony

I don't know how to run a Symfony project on Ubuntu server. I've tried the same way but could not get the path.

Comment: `same way?` which way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your project under /var/www/html/your-project

setup an apache virtual host under /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourproject.conf like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourproject.lan
    ServerAlias yourproject.lan

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourproject/web
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    <Directory /var/www/html/yourproject/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/your_project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/your_project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

enable your site with `sudo a2ensite yourproject`

edit your hosts file under /etc/hosts and add
127.0.0.1  yourproject.lan

reset apache with `sudo service apache2 restart` and then in your browser type yourproject.lan and you should be able to see something.

Comment: thanks @Herr Nentu, it's work